# Making multiple queries using JPA, Spring, Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I have recently configured my first JPA, Spring and Hibernate app to manage Users and Roles.

I have used The crudRepository to create my queries.  I have two Repositories, one for Users, and one for Roles.

Initially I Autowired my repositories to a Controller, then called them like this:

```
Role godRole = roleRepository.findByName(roleName);
User newUser = new User("me@me.net", "mARK");

newUser.addRole(godRole);

userRepository.save(newUser);
```

This resulted in an exception:

```
org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: uk.org.rspca.secrets.entities.Role
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:139)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:801)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:794)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener$1.cascade(JpaPersistEventListener.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:293)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:379)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:319)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:296)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeAfterSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:460)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:294)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:137)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaPersistEventListener.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:75)
```

I assume this is happening because each query is run in a separate session, therefore the by the time I try to add the Role to the User, the role is n longer attached to a session and because it has an Id it tries to do an insert instead of matching it with an existing Role.

I read that if the method carrying out the queries uses the @Transaction annotation that the queries would all run in the same session, this doesn't seem to have made a difference!

Can anyone she any light on how I should be trying to implement this behaviour, it seems like a fairly simple thing to want to be able to do!

applicationContext.xml

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="uk.co.secrets" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="jdbc/DBPool" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<data:repositories base-package="uk.co.secrets.repositories" />
```

User.java

```
 @Entity
@Table(name="S_User")
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column(name="u_pk_id")
    //@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "S_User_Seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "S_User_Seq", sequenceName = "S_User_Seq", allocationSize = 1)
    private long id;

    @Column(name="u_username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name="u_name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="u_last_login")
    private Date lastLoggedin;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "S_UserRole", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name="u_fk_id") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "r_fk_id") })
    private Set<Role> userRoles = new HashSet<Role>();
}
```

Role.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="S_Role")
public class Role {

    @Id
    @Column(name="r_pk_id")
    //@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "S_Role_Seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "S_Role_Seq", sequenceName = "S_Role_Seq", allocationSize = 1)
    private long id;

    @Column(name="r_name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="r_desc")
    private String description;

    @Column(name="r_created")
    private Date dateCreated;

    @Column(name="r_modified")
    private Date dateModified;

    @Column(name="r_removed")
    private Date dateremoved;
}
```

Regards mARK

Comment: So you are right, the method that does several queries should have the @Transactional annotation - is the object that has this method created/managed by Spring? If not, then no AOP wiring will happen and the transaction manager code will not get invoked

Comment: The User Service is annotated to autowire the user repositories, and my Controller class has the @Controller and relevant annotations, but the Controller class itself, is not created in spring config.  Could this be why the transaction is not used correctly for this?

Answer (score 0):

Your controller method should be annotated with @Transactional.
In your code, new transaction is created when you invoke repository method and is closed after method completion.

Anyway, it's a bad practice to start transaction in controller. 
It's better to create some service layer(transactional) between your controller and dao layers.

Comment: I am aware that the design will evolve, I am just trying to make this work at the moment. My Controller, even with the Transactional annotation still does not work, gives the same message as above!

Comment: Can you post your Role and User classess?

Comment: Added them to the original post

Comment: Try to remove CascadeType.ALL in a User -- Role relationship (or indicates operations you need except CascadeType.PERSIST)

PS. I can't believe @Transactional didn't help :)

Comment: According to all I've read, It should, Bret commented that I should try making sure that the Controller should be created in the spring config, but I thought this was messy, so have created a UserService Object (like you suggested), and created this in the Config, giving it the user repositories as properties, but this also failed!  Little bit annoying.  THis is supposed to make my database access 'easier' currently spring JDBC templates is the easier and better option for me... How sad!

Comment: How is your component created? I can't see <context:component-scan/> or <mvc:annotation-driven/> declaration in your ApplicationContext.xml

Comment: Piotr,  removing the cascade = CascadeType.ALL made it work....  Now I want to understand why.  Thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 0):

CascadeType.ALL means all operations made on the User object will be made on the Role object.

In this case, SAVE operation is cascaded to object Role which is detached now. That's why hibernate throw exception.

I'm curious why the Role object is being detached from session. When you made method Transactional (default propagation.Requires so it should create new transaction if no exists) and get your Role you should still have the same session.

EDIT:
I checked it on my project. You can't save an entity with id (especially when you have @GeneratedValue annotation). So you can't cascade persist operation to Role entity. 
So removing CascadeType.ALL is the only solution IMO. Of course you can set CascadeType.UPDATE, CascadeType.REMOVE and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the information Piotr.  I must say, I am a little disappointed with JPA/Spring/Hibernate.  I expected it to make my life easier, but infact I could've written the entire app in the time it's taken for me to work out how JPA is working!  I'm sure once you understand it all, it's much better.  My next challenge is bi-directional relationships.  Again should work just by including a Many-to-Many Annotation on the child object, but doesn't seem to work!  Frustrating!

Comment: Once you understand it, you'll like it ;)
If you have small application and you develop it alone, you may think it would be faster and easier without those frameworks.
When you work in a team (6-8 developers) and you have to make a large project you apprieciate advantages given by Spring or Hibernate.